# How to mock a class in Python?

Tags: python, testing

I'm new to Python, but I used to work with ruby.

I'm trying to do some tests with Python but I can't figure out how I mock a class for my test.

Let's say I have this real class:

```
from database import DB
class Foo:
  def do_it(self):
    x = {'key': 'value'}
    DB.save(x)
    # do other stuff with x
    return x
```

Now, I want to test if everything I'm doing with x returns me the right result, and I want to test if DB.save was called with x as parameter, but I don't want to actually save x to database. To see if DB.save is being called, I can use some mock framework, but how can I tell Foo class that I need it to use the mock object and not the real DB object?

Thank You.

**EDIT:**
Sorry, my example wasn't enough for what I need to accomplish.

Let's see this new example:

```
from database import DB
class Foo:
  DB.connect()
  def do_it(self):
    x = {'key': 'value'}
    DB.save(x)
    # do other stuff with x
    return x
```

And for instance, let's say the database is down.

When I import Foo, it raises the connection error and I do not have time to mock DB.

What should I do??

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The answer is, don't write your classes like that. It's a strange way to do so anyway - there shouldn't really be any executable code at the class level, other than attribute and method definitions. You should setup the connection in the `__init__` method.

```
class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        DB.connect()
```

Answer (score 6):

`DB` will be looked up in the module's scope everytime `Foo.do_it()` gets called.  You can simply assign a different object to `DB` and it will be used.  If your class `Foo` is in some module `foo`, you can do something like

```
import foo
foo.DB = mocked_DB
f = foo.Foo()
f.do_it()
```

Comment: This is known as monkey-patching, by the way.

Comment: Sven, your answer is correct and helped me solve the problem as well as Daniel's answer, but I need to choose one of them. Sorry, I wish I could mark both as right.